# Data passed to text boxes in bootstarp modal are restting automatically after loading modal if i click on anywhere in the modal

Tags: jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Hi i am trying to make a form in bootstrap modal. This modal is going to open based on a href click event. This a href tag is going to b generated dynamically in ajax call using Jquery.

format of the a href tag is below to call bootstrap modal.

```
'<a id="addvideo" data-toggle="modal" data-title="'+field.title+'" data-id="'+field.video_id+'" data-desc="'+field.description+'" data-channelname="'+field.channel_name+'" data-yudate="'+field.created_date+'" href="#form-content">'+field.title+'</a>'
```

The modal which i am calling is below shown.

```
                <div id="form-content" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                        <h3>Add Video</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form name="addvideo" action="#" id="addvideo">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <input type="text" id="videotitle" name="videotitle" value="" /><br />
                            <label>Video ID</label>
                            <input type="text" id="videoid" name="videoid" value="" /><br />
                            <label>Description</label>
                            <textarea name="videodesc" id="videodesc"></textarea><br />
                            <label>Channel</label>
                            <input type="text" id="channelname" name="channelname" value="" /><br />
                            <label>Actors</label>
                            <input type="text" id="actors" name="actors" value="" /><br />
                            <label>Directors</label>
                            <input type="text" id="directors" name="directors" value="" /><br />
                            <label>Producers</label>
                            <input type="text" id="producers" name="producers" value="" /><br />
                            <label>Order Number</label>
                            <input type="text" id="orderno" name="orderno" value="" /><br />
                            <label>Youtube Updated Date</label>
                            <input type="text" id="yudate" name="yudate" value="" /><br />
                            <label>CMS Updated Date</label>
                            <input type="text" id="cudate" name="cudate" value="" /><br />
                            <label class="checkbox">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="hidevideo"> Hide video in mobile app
                            </label>
                            <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit"><i class="icon-white icon-ok"></i> Submit</button>
                            <button class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="icon-white icon-circle-arrow-left"></i> Cancel</button>
                         </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Now to call modal based on click i am using below javascript code and in this code only i am passing data to modal by setting textboxes in modal using Jquery like below.

```
$(document).on("click", "#addvideo", function () {
 var videoid = $(this).data('id');
 var videotitle = $(this).data('title');
 var videodesc = $(this).data('desc');
 var channelname = $(this).data('channelname');
 var yudate = $(this).data('yudate');

 $(".modal-body #videoid").val( videoid );
 $(".modal-body #videotitle").val( videotitle );
 $(".modal-body #videodesc").val( videodesc );
 $(".modal-body #channelname").val( channelname );
 $(".modal-body #yudate").val( yudate );
});
```

Now my modal is loading fine and values are showing up in assigned textboxes once the modal loaded on click on href tag. But if i click on modal after loaded the values in text boxes are resetting to blank values automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `form` have the same ID than your `a` tag.

```
<a id="addvideo" ...>
<form name="addvideo" action="#" id="addvideo">
```

So the event `$(document).on("click", "#addvideo", function () {... })` will trigger on both elements. When `$(this)` refers to the form, your data are undefined / empty.

Just rename your form id and it should work.